# Symbolic Link from Workstation to Server

Tags: windows, network-share

What I'm trying to achieve is to sync Blink Recordings directly to our file server. 
The blink recording is save in the Appdata folder of the user profile.
I tried to use this commands but it only works for the user itself.

mklink /D "\192.168.0.21\d$\network_drive\IT\Test Sync" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Blink\recordings"

But other user or the server itself can't access the folder. Is there any other solution for this?

[image: screenshot: Location is not available]

Comment: Well, for one thing, `d$` is a special share available only to administrators.  You'll need to explicitly share the `network_drive` folder, or perhaps `IT` or `Test Sync` depending on your needs.

Comment: Symbolic links to network shares are also disabled by default, but it looks to me like you've already changed that.

Comment: \\192.168.0.21\network_drive\IT\Test Sync  I tried to use this sir but it's the same. BTW the network_drive folder is already a shared folder

Comment: The command as shown also seems to be back to front - that would create a symbolic link called `Test Sync` on the server pointing to a directory in `C:\Users`, don't you want it the other way around?

Comment: No sir. This is the scenario. From the Workstation(win10) I need to sync the call recordings from blink(soft phone) saved in this dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Blink\recordings into our File Server. The network drive folder is shared that holds all the files.

Comment: Is there any possible solution to sync folder through lan sir aside from symbolic link. If possible the sync is done automatically like a symbolic link

Comment: The way you're trying to create the symbolic link, even if it worked, none of the content would be stored on the file server.  If you tried to write to the directory on the file server you would actually be writing to a particular user's AppData folder, because that's where the symbolic link is pointing.  I really don't think that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Is there any possible solution sir?

Comment: A symbolic link might work, but it would have to be the other way around - pointing *from* the users folder *to* the file server.  But have you asked on the Blink support forum whether there is any way to reconfigure Blink to write the files to a specified location?